# UIScrollView top position changing when switching view

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView on a UITabBar app.
If the scrollview is left scrolled down when i change to a different view when changing back to it the position it was left in becomes the new top and i cannot scroll back up and there is whitespace added to the bottom.
How can i stop this from happening?

I have written a temporary fix by setting ViewWillDisappear to scroll to top.

Comment: Welcome to SO, you should post your code for us to help here.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and I also fixed it with viewWillDisappear. Here is the code I used.

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

[scroller2 scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 1297) animated:NO];

[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
```